# How can I configure WSO2 ESB 4.0.3 to use corporate proxy to access external web services (over HTTP)

Tags: web-services, proxy, wso2, esb, wso2-esb

I am trying to access external web services (outside of intranet) using [WSO2 ESB 4.0.3](http://wso2.com/products/enterprise-service-bus/) but I do not know how to configure the proxy to let the request go outside. I can send SOAP messages over HTTP from my basic Java client app without issues; I could specify teh proxy details using [Apache HttpComponents](http://hc.apache.org/). So, connection details are OK.

I tried:

1. Editing `<transportSender name="http" ... >` and specifying parameters like `"http.proxyHost"` and `"http.proxyPort"`.
2. Setting up a global parameter `<parameter name="Proxy"> ...`
3. Configuring the **HTTP Transport Sender** and specifying the appropriate parameters.

The best I got was:

```
 ERROR_CODE = 101503, ERROR_MESSAGE = Connection refused or failed for : ...
```

So, what did I wrong and what should I do instead? Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure you´ve set the transportSender parameters in the right file ? There is a documentation page about that for your ESB version that may help you:
https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB403/HTTP+Basic+Authentication+over+a+Proxy+Server

Answer (score 3):

Does your proxy server has any authentication? If yes and it uses Basic Auth you need to specify followoing properties before sending out the request..

```
<property name="Proxy-Authorization" expression="fn:concat('Basic', base64Encode('userName:password'))" scope="transport"/>
<property name="POST_TO_URI" value="true" scope="axis2"/>
```

The first property sets the Proxy-Authorization HTTP transport header with the base64 encoded user name and password as expected by the HTTP basic authentication.

The second property makes the out-going URL a complete URL understandable by the Proxy Server.

Following is an example proxy config...

```
<proxy name="StockQuoteProxy" startOnLoad="true">
<target>
<inSequence>
<property name="Proxy-Authorization" expression="fn:concat('Basic ', base64Encode('udayanga:test123'))" scope="transport"/>
<property name="POST_TO_URI" value="true" scope="axis2"/>
<send>
<endpoint>
<address uri="http://www.wso2.com:9000/services/SimpleStockQuoteService"/>
</endpoint>
</send>
</inSequence>
<outSequence>
<send/>
</outSequence>
</target>
<publishWSDL uri="file:repository/samples/resources/proxy/sample_proxy_1.wsdl"/>
</proxy>
```

Comment: Sorry, but this is not a solution to my problem. Our corporate proxy does not require authentication. I just would like to access, say `http://www.webserviceX.NET/GetQuote` instead of the WSO2 sample Axis2 server services. Any simple way to specify a proxy (and not a proxy service provided by WSO2 ESB)?

Comment: BTW, why cannot have the `<endpoint>` a `<proxyAddress>` or similar child element?